# Excel VBA Userform Web Browser

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set up a custom web browser using a user form in Excel VBA:

[image]

I then double click on object to edit code to this:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_StatusTextChange(ByVal Text As String)
WebBrowser1.Navigate ("http://www.bbc.co.uk")
End Sub
```

For some reason, it does not work and my web object remains blank when running it.

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Is the event being triggered?  If you put `Msgbox "OK"` in there does it show?

Comment: You are right, it is not triggered.. msgbox(ok) not working. What am I missing?

Comment: The `WebBrowser1_StatusTextChange` event occurs when the status bar changes.  What do you actually want to happen?

Comment: I have created an user feedback button in custom ribbon using xml. What I envisage is a user clicking on feedback button, it will open this web browser to fill the form.  Somethng like this: 'Private Sub Feedback(control As IRibbonControl)

    Webbrowser.Show

End Sub'

Comment: @OdaySalim -  I'm curious how you got the web browser control onto the userform?

Comment: Tools --> additional controls --> Microsoft Web Browser

Comment: @ashleedawg - I use this control and it works pretty well...

Comment: Sorry - what am I missing?

Comment: Try moving your code the the userform's `Activate` event.

Comment: @TimWilliams - can you please show me how? Thanks

Comment: Initialize event might be more suitable... https://www.homeandlearn.org/the_form_initialize_event.html

Comment: @TimWilliams Can you please write a solution to how you think it will work. It is not working for me. I am really banging my head over this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
     Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
End Sub
```