# Show HTML in Excel Sidebar (like Helppages) with VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

Is it possible to view a webpage (or local html-file) in a new sidebar, like the integrated help-pages do? And what would be the vba code to launch it? [image]

I'd like to provide some help-files with my xlam but don't want to use the old chm-files...

Comment: The one that I can think of is to create userform web-browser : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806681/excel-vba-userform-web-browser. Make a button to show the userform at the same time resize the active sheet and put on the left also make a code to set the userform position on the right.

Comment: Hi karma, thanks for the suggestion! This would be a solution but not as handy as the fixed sidebar, especially for help files that i like to view while working on the sheet.

Comment: I think you still can work on the sheet if you show the userform vbmodeless.